# How to build and install an Eclipse plugin using ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

How do I build and install an Eclipse plugin using ant? I want to build a plugin as a zip file and then install the plugin on 32bit or 64bit eclipse. What am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, using [PDE/Build](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-build/) to achieve a so-called `headless build` is difficult, but not impossible.

We are still building our RCP this way.

I recommend reading [Paulin's](http://www.modumind.com/2007/06/06/getting-started-with-pde-build/) and [Sharma's](http://blog.ankursharma.org/2010/06/headless-build-for-beginners-part-i.html) tutorials on the issue.

Comment: i used the method as <a href="http://blog.ankursharma.org/2010/06/headless-build-for-beginners-part-i.html" > Sharma's tutorials</a> told, it said "build successful", but xx.zip did not appear as expected. the log appears lots of error and warning. i don't know why, because the plugin can export by eclipse.

Comment: You'll have to correct the build errors. If you can export your plugin from Eclipse, this is probably a build configuration issue (target platform?)

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse PDE has its own builder which is built on ant. I'm not sure from your question if you are looking to simply build/export your plugin within eclipse or generate ant build scripts that can be run outside of eclipse. The latter is more difficult. Inside eclipse you can simple go to file -> export -> Plugin-Development -> Deployable plugin and the export wizard will walk you through it, you can select to deploy a zip or exploded directory and then select output location and presto you have your plugin built as a jar that can be dropped into an eclipse instance. If you are looking to use ant outside of eclipse to build you need to go through a series of steps that are complicated to get a 'headless build", if this is what you need to do Google "pde headless" build. I've tried it but gave up. There is also a good book "Building highly modular systems with OSGI/Equinox that has a chapter devoted to this. -  Duncan

Comment: i use ant outside eclipse to build a plugin. i use the first method to create a build.xml but this is not useful

Comment: Have fun, its complicated but possible. Need to copy the ant files from the pde.core plgin in workspace .settings if I remember right, then customize to select target environmnet and other stuff. Maybe there are some build tools otu there that address.